# Alpha hydrogen and hyperconjugation

Tags: organic-chemistry, hyperconjugation

Why do we say that an alpha hydrogen is necessary for hyperconjugation? What exactly is an alpha hydrogen? From what I read online, it is the hydrogen attached to a functional group. Why is that required?

For example, in $\ce{CH3-CH=CH2}$, hyperconjugation takes place, but I don't see clearly any functional group that would facilitate it.

Alternatively, in $\ce{CH3-COOH}$ it does not take place.

Why is this?

Answer (score 6):

To remember:

Hyperconjugation is the stabilising interaction that results from the interaction of the electrons in a σ-bond (usually C-H or C-C) with an adjacent empty or partially filled p-orbital or a π-orbital to give an extended molecular orbital that increases the stability of the system. [Further information](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch04/ch4-3-2-1.html).

**The proposed systems to take into account.**

Looking at the resonance structures (which is a synonym of [mesomeric effect](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03844.html)) of the propene

[image: Resonance structures of propene]
<sub>(source: [tutorvista.com](http://image.tutorvista.com/content/organic-chemistry/hyper-conjugation-propene.gif))</sub>

and acetic acid

[image: Resonance structures of acetic acid]
<sub>(source: [nonsibihighschool.org](http://nonsibihighschool.org/intbasch9_files/aceticFC.png))</sub>

Therefore, in hyperconjugation analysis you need to look at the position of the electron density. Not the vicinal hydrogen.

Moreover and with the aim to give a complete answer, the hyperconjugation of the acetic acid can be very well understood at [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27799/hyper-conjugation-in-acetic-acid).

Comment: Your pic is for mesomeric stabilisation of acetate not hyperconiugation of acetic acid.

Comment: But  why does hyperconjugation not take place in acetic acid? Besides, why can only alpha hydrogen participate? Can you explain more about the electron density part?

Comment: @Shodai, I invite you to take a look at: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27799/hyper-conjugation-in-acetic-acid

Comment: @Shodai, also, the relevance of the alpha hydrogen to a functional group with a carbonil is when you are doing a synthesis through an electrophilic substitution at this hydrogen. If this is what you want to know. I recommend you this site: https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/crbacid3.htm